# How to serialize only part of a list in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization

Using WPF with C#, I am looking for a way to serialize only a part of a list. I know it is possible to find out if the list is empty, and serialize is only if it is not. However, I wish to look at members of elements of a list, and depending on their value, serialize them or not.

For example: from the class below, elements from list "fields" of class Sub2ClassType should only appear in the XML when their member "strValue" is not equal to "".

Is this possible? I tried various ways, including code for Onserialize(), but to no avail.

```
namespace somenamespace
{
    [Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "dashboard", ElementName = "dashboardSettings")]
    public class dashboardSettings
    {
        [XmlElement("sub1class", Namespace = "")]
        public Sub1Class sub1class{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub1Class
    {
        [XmlElement("sub2class")]
        public ObservableCollection<Sub2Class> sub2class{ get; set; }

        public Sub1Class()
        {
            sub2class = new ObservableCollection<Sub2Class>();
        }
    }

    public class Sub2Class : Patch
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string strName{ get; set; }
        [XmlElement("type")]
        public Sub2ClassType type{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Sub2ClassType
    {
        [XmlAttribute("name")]
        public string type{ get; set; }
        // These should only be serialized if member strValue != ""
        [XmlElement("elems", IsNullable = false)] 
        public ObservableCollection<Sub2ClassField> fields{ get; set; }

        public PatchTypeDetectionType()
        {
            fields = new ObservableCollection<Sub2ClassField>();
        }
    }

    public class Sub2ClassField
    {
        [XmlAttribute("field")]
        public string strField{ get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("value")]
        public string strValue{ get; set; }

        public DSIField()
        {
            strField = "";
            strValue = "";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return strValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create new, filtered list and serialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ShouldSerialze. refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public class Sub2ClassField
{
    [XmlAttribute("field")]
    public string strField { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializestrField()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue);
    }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string strValue { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializestrValue()
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue);
    }

    public Sub2ClassField()
    {
        strField = "";
        strValue = "";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return strValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you also @Ganesh. This works partly, but will still leave an empty XmlElement in the resulting XML file (one <elems /> for each element in the list). It is not a big problem, but preferable would be to omit those elements altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Just filter it using Linq.

```
serializer.Serialize(mylist.Where(e => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.strValue)).ToList());
```

Comment: Thank you @Kai Brummond for your quick reply. Does this also work given that I have a List inside another List? So far my approach to serialization was to just serialize the main class, using XmlSerializer: serializer.Serialize(writer, dashboardSettingsInstance);

Comment: Not really, but see @Ganesh s answer for that case.